# How to express something that is happening in the future

Tags: grammar, tense, usage, past-continuous

If something is being written in the past tense, is it correct to say:

> He was graduating high school in June and entering college in August?

How should it be stated?

Answer (score 1):

Heh heh. The past-and-possible-never tense.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtcAVxoz6S8

Several possible choices exist depending on how you want to lay things out, and what point of view you want to apply.

Laying it out from his point of view before it happened, but with future absolute knowledge.

> He was planning to graduate high school in June and enter college in August.

Could also use "expected", "anticipated", etc.

Laying it out as events that would take place, but that had not yet.

> He would graduate high school in June and enter college in August.

Alternatively, from the point of view of an omniscient narrator before the events.

> He would be graduating high school in June and entering college in August.

Laying it out as recounting historical events, possibly the most simple.

> He graduated high school in June and entered college in August.